# SipAudioCall.endCall doesn't reject the call

Tags: android, sip

I am developing a simple application that allows user to initiate call using sip protocol.

In my IncomingCallActivity I have 2 buttons: accept or decline the call.
Accept onClickListener:

```
View.OnClickListener accept = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            incomingCall.answerCall(30);
        } catch (SipException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

decline listener:

```
View.OnClickListener decline = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            incomingCall.endCall();
        } catch (SipException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

The problem is, that `endCall()` doesn't reject it and the caller still waiting for some sip packets about rejecting his call.

How can I alert a caller about rejecting his call?

Comment: when you call `endCall`, can you still hear the caller from the other end?

Comment: no. When I drop call after connect, it works fine.
The problem is only when I want to drop it without answer a call.

Comment: is this app used on both ends of the call? or are you using this on one end and on another, an app available in Google Store? I can see that you are trying to reject the `incomingCall` based on your code.

Comment: 1) First device uses [Zoiper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zoiper.android.app);
2) I am using my Application;
3) First device is calling me, I reject this call.. First device is still waiting, but nothing happens.
P.S. When I try the same scheme with zoiper only (calling with zoiper to zoiper), it works fine.

Comment: from which Listener Callback method did you get your `incomingCall` object?

Comment: I get call object from SipManager.takeAudioCall:
`incomingCall = sipDataManager.getSipManager().takeAudioCall(intent, listener)`

Comment: have you tried getting the AudioCall object from onRinging() as described in my anwer?

Comment: I am trying now, but I don't understand why 'onRinging()' is not called. Other callbacks such as `onChanged` and `onCallEnded` are called

Answer (score 0):

I did this a year ago but could no longer find my Sip app source code. From what I remember, I get the `incomingCall` object from `SipAudioCall.Listener`'s `onRinging()` method. Then call `endCall()` from that object.

```
SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
   @Override
   public void onRinging(SipAudioCall call, SipProfile caller) {
      try {
         //call.answerCall(30);
         // 1. Save SipAudioCall object into your incoming call
         incomingCall = call;
         // 2. In your DECLINE View.OnClickListener, call endCall()
         //    on this same object 
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
};
```

Comment: based on your comment, the onRinging() was never called MIGHT be because you called `incomingCall = sipDataManager.getSipManager().takeAudioCall(intent, listener);` right inside the `onReceive()`. You should take/reject the call inside your `AudioCall.Listener` as SIP calling is an Asynchronous task.

Comment: How can I get SipAudioCall inside listener? I need a SipAudioCall object to set listener for it. And I am using `takeAudioCall(callIntent, callListener)` to get it.

Comment: were you able to figure this out?